# How to manually boot a system to cobbler and assign a kickstart profile base on MAC without PXE

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, kickstart, cobbler

I can manually point a linux host to the cobbler server's kickstart profile from the centos 7 boot screen by plugging in `inst.ks=http://10.1.1.1:80/cblr/svc/op/ks/profile/derpprofile` and that works (I could create a CD to do this automatically).

But now that I have that working I want to be able to direct machines to different profiles based on mac address.

I can add them to cobbler first like this:

```
cobbler system add --name=derpsystem --profile=derpprofile --mac-address=00:15:5D:66:EA:0E --interface=eth0
cobbler system add --name=herpsystem --profile=herpprofile --mac-address=00:15:5D:66:EA:0E --interface=eth0
```

I want to have a CD that boots to a *generic* profile and then cobbler decides which profile to apply to which machine by looking at the mac and assigning the profile I associated with that system.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using `cobbler buildiso`? It's been a while, but I don't think that works for Cobbler built ISOs. (It does when PXE booting.) I know I am commenting on an old question, so maybe you have already found a solution. If so, please let us know!